# multiple commands by logging into SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to log in to the server and give multiple commands from the input file. Here input file is web.txt (contains 'bash', 'df-g' as examples). I am sucessfully able to login to server, but not able to run the commands. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help me please.

```
import paramiko


web_list = []
def create_web_list():
    file = open("web.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
    for value in file.readlines():
        web_list.append(value.strip( ))
    return web_list

ip = 'x.x.x.x'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

def web_device(web_list):
    SESSION = paramiko.SSHClient()
    SESSION.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
    SESSION.connect(ip,port=22,username=username,password=password,look_for_keys=False,allow_agent=False)
    print("Connection Sucessful")

    for cmd in web_list:
        stdin,stdout,stderr=SESSION.exec_command(cmd)
        outlines=stdout.readlines()
        resp=''.join(outlines)
        print(resp)

    SESSION.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web_device(create_web_list())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify either you want output in one go or you want output for each command separately? if you want with one go then please find below:
Executing multiple commands on paramiko SSHClient, you can place all commands in one line with `;` separator like:
`client.exec_command('ls -l; cwd; whoiam')` etc
so please read line from file accordingly and execute commands with one go instead using a loop.

For Individual command execution case use below:

```
with open("web.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
   return web_list.append(f.strip( ))
```

and print output in utf format like `'\n'.join(outlines)`

Comment: No, I have 500 commands to run on the server every day. It will be easy for me if I give input from a file.

Comment: do you want to execute one by one each or its okay if you read all commands once, execute those and see output in sequential order at once?

Comment: I need to execute one by one command.

Comment: If your connection is successfully **established** then please try `'\n'.join(outlines)` to join output in 'utf8' readable format. and try to use below code for file reading:  
`with open("web.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    return web_list.append(f.strip( ))`

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer as useful and vote it!

Comment: Sure. I will accept your answer as useful